# Button Press/Loading Webpage in RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to automate a search with RSelenium and struggling immensely. Everything seems to work, but whenever I run the code to press the search button, it seems to click but not actually search. I've scoured the history of RSelenium related questions here and I'm not finding a solution that works...any suggestions from the clever folks here? Reproducible example of the code below, just have to load the libraries and start your machine/driver of choice.

```
# Go to License Plate lookup page
mydriver$navigate("https://checktoprotect.org/vin-check/")

# Enter state
dropdown_element <- mydriver$findElement(using = "xpath", value='//*[@id="state-select"]/div[1]')
dropdown_element$clickElement()
state_element <- mydriver$findElement(using = "xpath", value='//*[@id="state-select"]/div[2]/div[23]')
state_element$clickElement()

# Enter License Plate
plate_element <- mydriver$findElement(using = "xpath", value='//*[@id="js-vin-input"]')
plate_element$sendKeysToElement(list("ELX1701"))

# Click submit
submit1_element <- mydriver$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="js-vin-btn"]')
submit1_element$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a better and lighter approach (`rselenium` is my enemy):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

session <- "https://checktoprotect.org/vin-check/" %>% 
  session()

result <- session %>% 
  html_form() %>% 
  pluck(1) %>% 
  html_form_set(state_id = "MI", 
                plate_number = "ELX1701") %>% 
  html_form_submit() %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_elements("strong , .recalls__no-results p , .clear , .recalls__model") %>% 
  html_text()

> result
[1] "0 Open Recalls for:"                                                                                    
[2] "2015 GMC SIERRA 1500"                                                                                   
[3] "1GTR1TEH8FZ298242"                                                                                      
[4] "MI - ELX1701"                                                                                           
[5] "New recalls are issued regularly. We recommend checking every 3 months for new recalls on your vehicle."
```

Comment: You're my hero. Seriously, I initially had been working with rvest and saw a lot of comments suggesting it would be more difficult to get the results using that instead of rselenium...knowing I can use that (and understand the code a little better as I do it) makes things immeasurably easier on me. Thank you!